# Why does this docker compose file build the same image four times?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose build` on the following `docker-compose` file, which is for a django server with celery, it builds an identical image four times (for the `web` service, `celeryworker`, `celerybeat` and `flower`).

The entire process is repeated four times

I thought the point of inheriting from other service descriptions in docker-compose was so that you could reuse the same image for different services?

**How can I reuse the `web` image in the other services, to reduce my build time by 75%?**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: &django
    image: myorganisation/myapp
    container_name: myapp_web
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
        # This is a multistage build installing private dependencies, hence this arg is needed
        args:
          PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GITHUB}
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=backend.settings.local
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres_user:postgres_password@db/postgres_db
      - REDIS_URL=redis://:redis_password@redis:6379
      - CELERY_FLOWER_USER=flower_user
      - CELERY_FLOWER_PASSWORD=flower_password
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    container_name: myapp_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    container_name: myapp_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    container_name: myapp_flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    command: /start-flower

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  pgadmin_data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are specifying the `build` section in all the services (using the `django` anchor), it is getting built for every service.

If you want to use the same image for all services but build it only once, you can specify the `build` section in only one service which would be started first (i.e., service with no dependencies) and then specify just the `image` field without `build` section the in other services and make these services depend on the first service which builds the image.

Comment: so repeat `image: myorganisation/myapp` in the others, but lose the `<<<django`?

Comment: yes. basically have the `build` section in one service, repeat `image` in all services, make all services depend_on the service that has the `build` section.